# Django. model.ImageField

Tags: python, django

Недавно начал работу с Django и натолкнулся на проблему.
Из формы (администратора) запрашивается изображение. С загрузкой всё корректно, но файл сохраняется в корень, а мне нужно, чтобы он сохранялся в static, т.к. потом я вызываю этот файл через {% load static %}. Почему-то в HTML-коде файл высвечивается только из статика, а из корня нет. Приходилось вручную вырезать и вставлять файл в нужную папку. Помогите, пожалуйста, прописать пусть сохранения из класс models.ImageField в /static. Заранее, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django вроде как не загружает изображения с помощью `{% load static %}`. Вам нужно в файле `settings.py` указать `MEDIA_URL` и `MEDIA_ROOT`. Пример использования:

## settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [....
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## models.py

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/', blank=True, null=True)
```

По итогу путь к картинке будет иметь вид `/media/users/your_image.jpg`.

Далее передаёте при рендеринге передаёте это объект в ваш темплейт. Ссылка на картинку доступна через `object.image.url`.

Comment: В HTML коде, когда пишу <img src="../../../media/users/{{post.image}}" width="100%"> картинка не проявляется, хотя надписи к ней есть

Comment: вам не нужно писать `/media/users/{{post.image}}` это за вас сделает `{{post.image.url}}`

Comment: Всё равно не видит((

Comment: {% for post in object_list %}
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="{{post.image.url}}" width="100%">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3 class="text-dark">{{post.title}}</h3>
                                    <p class="text-light">{{post.text}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}

Comment: @kurpenok дополнил ответ